# Type mismatch error when folding a List[Int] with scala.math.pow: found Double, required Int

Tags: scala

I'm getting a type mismatch error when using math.pow()

```
@ List(1,2,3).foldLeft(1)( (x,y) => scala.math.pow(x,y) ) 
  cmd28.sc:1: type mismatch;
  found   : Double
  required: Int
  val res28 = List(1,2,3).foldLeft(1)( (x,y) => scala.math.pow(x,y) )
                                                        ^
  Compilation Failed
```

If I just run it with the first to elements of List it works as expected.

```
@ scala.math.pow(1,2) 
  res28: Double = 1.0
```

Furthermore, the function definition in the repl (amm) shows that it's expecting doubles.

```
@ scala.math.pow <tab>
 def pow(x: Double, y: Double): Double
```

So, why am I getting an error `found Double, required Int`?  I've tried passing doubles and Ints

```
math.scala.pow(x.toDouble, y.toDouble)
```

but I get the same error message.

Comment: The 1st argument in `foldLeft()` sets the output type. `1` is an `Int`. Change it to `1.0` or `1D` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the type signature of [`foldLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldLeft%5BB%5D(z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) you can see that it looks like this:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

So, let's see where you call it:

```
List(1,2,3).foldLeft(1)( (x,y) => scala.math.pow(x,y) )
```

So the initial value is a `1` of type **Int**, so the function should be of type **(Int, Int) => Int**, so the function should return an **Int**, but it returns a **Double**.

You can fix it either like this:
*(returns an **Int**)*

```
List(1,2,3).foldLeft(1) {
  case (acc, x) => math.pow(acc, x).toInt
}
```

Or like this:
*(returns a **Double**)*

```
List(1,2,3).foldLeft(1.0d) {
  case (acc, x) => math.pow(acc, x)
}
```

---

BTW, both options will return `1`, because `1^x` always returns `1`; which is not probably what you want, which probably means you do not understand how `foldLeft` works. I would suggest you looking in the internet for a detailed explanation of how the operation is applied from left t right.
Also, this has nothing to do with **Ammonite**.